# Populating a 2 dimensional Range in excel using sum ifs function in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Data in a sheet with profit which is based on the store and location. Looking to have a matrix with location in one column and stores in a row. For each location and store it would return one value which is the sum of the profit for all stores (there maybe multiple stores in a particular location) in that location.

This would be the excel function:

=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet1!$A5,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,Sheet1!B$4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like,

```
with sheets("Sheet1")
    with .range("B5:Z99")
        .formula = "=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6, Sheet1!$A5, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6, Sheet1!B$4)"
        .value = .value
    end with 
end with
```

Essentially, write the formula into the block of cells then revert the formulas' results to their values.

**EDIT for dynamic last row:**

```
dim lr as long
lr = Sheets("Sheet2").cells(rows.count, 3).end(xlup).row
```

Then the formula assignment would be:

```
.formula = "=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$" & lr & ", Sheet2!$A$2:$A$" & lr & ", Sheet1!$A5, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$" & lr & ", Sheet1!B$4)"
```

**EDIT: Named Ranges:**

If you move to a formula utilizing named ranges to define the extents of the data being examined, use the same [MATCH formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to define the limits of different columns.

Example: In the above SUMIFS, you could use named ranges for Sheet2's columns A, B and C. Let's call the named ranges *ws2colA, ws2colB* and *ws2colC*. We know that we are summing columns C so use the row of the last number in column C to define the ranges for each of the columns.

```
ws2colA - Applies to:
=Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A, MATCH(1e99, Sheet2!$C:$C))

ws2colB - Applies to:
=Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B, MATCH(1e99, Sheet2!$C:$C))

ws2colC - Applies to:
=Sheet2!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C, MATCH(1e99, Sheet2!$C:$C))
```

The formula assignment becomes:

```
.formula = "=SUMIFS(ws2colC, ws2colA, Sheet1!$A5, ws2colB, Sheet1!B$4)"
```

Using the same formula to define the extents of each named range column will prevent mismatched range references in the SUMIFS.

Comment: This works however what do you suggest for the fact that my source data size is dynamic. For example:  Sheet2!$C$2:$C$&lastrow&     Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my edit above to accommodate a dynamic last row. A [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) can also use full column references without undue calculation lag if there are not values below the referenced cells that would interfer.

Comment: Named ranges can use a formula (**OFFSET**) to turn it into dynamic, no macros required.

Comment: @PatricK - Named ranges are better with the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) (e.g. `=Sheet2!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C, MATCH(1e99, Sheet2!$C:$C))`) and just as effective.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jeeped, I will try that. I use the Name Manager to create dynamic named range, say  `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$C:$C),COUNTA(Sheet2!$2:$2))` for a single table with header starting from Sheet2!$C$2. With a few of this dynamic named range, the ranges for SUMIFS can be read and maintained easier.

Comment: @PatricK - see my addendum on named ranges and the reasoning behind the method.